# karnaugh map simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I really wonder why my method is wrong. Could you explain step-by-step and why my methods wrong. Drawings includes just one time isn't it enough for simplification ?

First boolen expression: $$ F = A'B'C'D' + A'B'C'D + A'B'CD + A'B'CD' + A'BC'D + A'BCD + ABC'D + ABCD + AB'C'D' + AB'C'D + AB'CD + AB'CD' $$
[image]

my result:
$$ C'D + B'D + AB' + BD $$

Second boolean expression : $$ F = A'B'C'D + A'BC'D' + A'BC'D + A'BCD' + ABC'D' + ABC'D + ABCD' + AB'C'D' + AB'C'D + AB'CD + AB'CD'  $$
the other one

[image]

my second result:
$$ BD' + C'D + AB' $$

Comment: Your method could be right, depending on what boolean expressions you came up with from your pictures. I would suggest writing them.

Comment: I added my results but when I check both of them wrong. Actually, my grouping method wrong. @par

Answer (score 0):

[image: kmap]

You have 12 terms and only 11 1's.  You missed the 1st term on second row.

Second Kmap and answer is correct.

Edit...
You say:
$$F(ABCD) = AB′ + C′D + BC′ + BD′$$
is the correct answer for the second kmap.

Consensus Law says $X Y + X'Z + Y Z = X Y + X'Z$.

So rearranging to make it easier to see: $DC′ + D′B + C′B = DC′ + D′B$.

$BC'$ is redundant.

If you include $BC'$, you must also include $AD'$.  It's just as redundant.
$$BD′ + B′A + D'A = BD′ + B′A$$

The only correct answer for kmap 2  is:
$$F(ABCD) = AB′ + C′D + BD′$$

Comment: thank you. but for second kmap, right answer is showed $$ F(ABCD) = A B' + C' D + B C' + B D' $$

Comment: The B'C term is redundant. A kmap will produce minimal solution.  You could also add AD'.  It is redundant too.   The right answer is wrong.   Show your kmap to prove your answer is correct.